Properly segment video with mp4box.js
I'm trying to do client side segmenting of an mp4 video using mp4box.js just like in the docs example
var mp4boxfile = MP4Box.createFile();
mp4boxfile.onReady = function(info) {
  ...
  mp4boxfile.onSegment = function (id, user, buffer, sampleNumber, last) {}
  mp4boxfile.setSegmentOptions(info.tracks[0].id, sb, options);  
  var initSegs = mp4boxfile.initializeSegmentation();  
  mp4boxfile.start();
  ...
};

By storing the initSegment of the video track and all the following segments of the respective track.
The problem is when I try to play back that video the segments start one after another but I don't get an initial duration, and the video is always seeked at the end and keeps progressing. I guess this is related to fragmenting, since when I use the DASH_CONFORMANCE/TelecomParisTech sample dash files it works as expected.
I'd like to know the whole video duration upfront and be able to seek to random parts of the video (this part I guess I'll need to implement on my ownn).

Is the real question: How to add duration to an MP4 header?
